# How can I acces list items in c#

Tags: c#, list

I am making a very basic banking app and created csv file that holds the details of customers. I then read this csv file and convert the data into objects and properties of the Account class and stored these objects in a list. So i am trying to access the individual properties of these objects through the lists and i am getting an error. Is there a better way to access and use the object properties?

```
class Account
   {
    public string CustomerName;
    public string PIN;
    public double Balance;

    public Account(string rowData)
    {
        string[] data = rowData.Split(',');

        //parse data into properties
        this.CustomerName = data[0];
        this.PIN = data[1];
        this.Balance = Convert.ToDouble(data[2]);
    }

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ReadAccounts()
    {
        //Readthe contents of the csv file as individual lines
        string[] csvLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Accounts.csv");

        //accounts
        var accounts = new List<Account>();

        //split each row into column data
        for (int i = 1; i < csvLines.Length; i++)
        {
            Account acc = new Account(csvLines[i]);
            accounts.Add(acc);
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAccounts();
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; i++)
        {
            //code dependent on Account instance properties
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*i am getting an error.*" - is not a technical description of a problem

Comment: What TheGeneral is trying to say: What exactly is the error?

Comment: What is the error as others have said and where (line/lines) you are getting it?

Comment: My bad, the error say "The name 'accounts' does not exist in current context". This is under the Form2_Load method.

Comment: Change `public void ReadAccounts()` for `public List<Account> ReadAccounts()` and add a `return accounts;` as the last line of the method. Then you'll have the accounts in your `Form2_Load` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you problem is because you declare `var accounts = new List<Account>();` in `ReadAccounts()` which makes it local to that function and then attempt to access it in `Form2_Load` where it will be out of scope.

Declare `accounts` at a higher level e.g.:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<Account> Accounts {get;set;}

    public void ReadAccounts()
    {
        //Readthe contents of the csv file as individual lines
        string[] csvLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Accounts.csv");

        //accounts
        Accounts = new List<Account>();

        //split each row into column data
        for (int i = 1; i < csvLines.Length; i++)
        {
            Account acc = new Account(csvLines[i]);
            Accounts.Add(acc);
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAccounts();
        for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.Count; i++)
        {
            //code dependent on Account instance properties
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have done that and it's working, I am now able to access the properties but I am getting a new error that says property type 'List<Account>' is less accessible than property 'Form2.Accounts'.

Comment: Try declaring class `Account` public - `public class Account ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare accounts global to the class, not locally inside ReadAccounts function

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is because you declare accounts as a variable only in the scope of `ReadAccounts` with this line:

```
var accounts = new List<Account>();
```

This means that the method `Form2_Load()` doesn't know about `accounts`.

You have two options. One is to make accounts a variable declared in your class `Form2` like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
     var accounts = new List<Account>();
     ...
}
```

Or you could have `ReadAccounts` return the result to your `Form2_Load` method:

```
public List<Account> ReadAccounts()
{
    //Readthe contents of the csv file as individual lines
    string[] csvLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Accounts.csv");

    //accounts
    var accounts = new List<Account>();

    //split each row into column data
    for (int i = 1; i < csvLines.Length; i++)
    {
        Account acc = new Account(csvLines[i]);
        accounts.Add(acc);
    }


     return accounts;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var accounts = ReadAccounts();
     ...
}
```